# Comparing two sets of attributes from two datasets and updating third dataset with matches

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops, arcpy

I have a couple of questions about my code. One is why I'm having trouble with my uber-nested for loops, and the other is if anyone has any tips for improving my code in general.

I'm trying to write code that normalizes a small spatial dataset (inputDs) by comparing columns from it and a huge reference dataset called refDs, and then returns potential matches in a new table called "matches". The fields being compared are:

refDs latitude,
refDs longitude,
inputDs lat (which I copied to a list, inLat), 
inDs long (in another list, inLong),

refDs field "nameAttested" (the formal name of a location),
refDs field "nameTransliterated" (for the sake of this code, this is one or more alternate names for the location),
inDs nameAtt (copied to a list, inAtt),
inDs nameTrans (copied to a list, inTrans).

So for those of you who are counting, that's four lists-- one for each inputDs attribute, and four columns in a table, refDs, which are going to be compared. First, if the coordinates line up (within 5 of each other), the refDs and inputDs records are added to the new table "matches." Then, each of the name attributes has to be compared twice-- refAtt to inAtt, refTrans to inAtt, refAtt to inTrans, and refTrans to inTrans, and for each name match, a count attribute in matches ("mCount") gets += 1. Also, some nameTrans fields in both refDs and inDs have 0 names or more than 1.

The code below shows how I'm working on a nested insert cursor for my matches table, which iterates through my inLat and inLong lists, passing them and the refLat and refLong into the great circle distance function (which I successfully added). Take a look:

```
   # set variables
   lat1 = "reprLat"
   lon1 = "reprLong"
   lat2 = inLat
   lon2 = inLong
   refAtt = refDs.nameAttested
   refTrans = refDs.nameTransliterated

   # insertCursor for matches Table
    rows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(matches, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, refAtt, refTrans,"inAtt", 
    "inTrans", "mCount"])

    #searchcursor for refDs
    refCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(refDs, ["reprLat", "reprLong"])


   for i in lat2:
       for x in lon2:
            for y in lat1:
                for z in lon1:
                    if great_circle(lon1[0], lat1[0], lon2[0], lat2[0]) <= 5:
                        rows.insertRow()
                        for x in inAtt:
                            for y in inTrans:
                                for z in refAtt:
                                    for i in refTrans:
                                        if textdistance.jaro(refAtt, inAtt) >= 0.45:
                                            mCount += 1
                                        elif textdistance.jaro(refAtt, inTrans) >= 0.45:
                                            mCount += 1
                                        elif textdistance.jaro(refTrans, inAtt) >= 0.45:
                                             mCount += 1
                                        elif textdistance.jaro(refTrans, inTrans) >= 0.45:
                                             mCount += 1
```

I tested the first part (measuring distances), by running it in Juptyer with a simple, if ... <= 5, print"yes", else print "no". And no matter the number I measured the distances against (5, 20, 100, 1000), I either got all yeses or all nos. So I'm clearly doing something wrong. Can anyone tell me how to fix the semantics of that section?

Also, is there anyway to make all this nesting ... more elegant? I only started to learn to code this year, and I'm still learning a lot of basic things and making elementary errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe a more elegant way of using for loops. Go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173168/avoiding-nested-for-loops-python

Comment: I think this line should be like this ```rows = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(matches, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, refAtt, refTrans,"inAtt", 
    "inTrans", "mCount"])```

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag Thank you for that link! I don't fully understand what's going on in that code, but I will study it and see if I can find ways to adapt it to mine.