# Python - Avoiding Nested 'for' Loops To Make Code More Efficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have two datasets:

- First dataset represents a table with **locomotive information**.
- Second dataset represents a table containing **exchanged messages** between locomotives and control center.

I want to get the number of messages per locomotive that had a delivery time more than or equal to **300 seconds**.

[image]

In order to calculate this, I wrote the following code (*dataframe 1 is 'df_loco', dataframe 2 is 'df_sent'*):

```
    for i in range(0, len(df_loco['LOCO']),1):
      for j in range(0,len(df_sent['HM_ID_HM']),1):
        if (df_sent.iloc[j,1] == df_loco.iloc[i,0]) and (df_sent.iloc[j,11]>=a):
            df_loco.iloc[i,4] += 1
```

The code does the job and gives me the correct number of messages that suffered delays. However, my dataset is big (dataframe 1 is 300+ rows, dataframe 2 is 55.000+) so it takes a long time to execute it.

I have been able to get rid of nested for loops in parts of my code which made it 100x more efficient. But here I'm having issues implementing the 'and' operator while not using 'for' loops. It returns me an error stating that the code is too ambiguous(?).

**Question:**
Is there a way to improve this code, not having to work with nested loops?

Comment: You should be able to find some ideas at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462325/python-avoid-nested-for-loop

Comment: As a first attack, look at `itertools` package.  You will want the `product` of the two ranges.  More than that, learn to use the full-column operations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [avoiding nested for loops python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173168/avoiding-nested-for-loops-python)

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas you could merge the 2 dataframes with a left join, filter for DELIVERY_TIME > 300 and then use groupby to get a count for LOCO_ID.

```
import pandas as pd

df_loco = pd.DataFrame({'LOCO_ID':[123, 456, 789, 321]})
df_sent = pd.DataFrame({'MESSAGE_ID':range(1, 7),'LOCO_ID':[456, 123, 123, 321, 789, 123], 'DELIVERY_TIME':[14,800, 420,310,60, 14]})

merged_dataframe = df_loco.merge(df_sent, how='left')

count_dataframe = merged_dataframe[merged_dataframe['DELIVERY_TIME']>300].groupby('LOCO_ID')['LOCO_ID'].count()

print(count_dataframe)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I've applied it on my two dataframes and it worked!
Just one question, how can I have it added to the column 'COUNT_DELAYS' instead of 'count_dataframe'?